# How to put social bar above top nav

Tags: css, responsive

I want show social media icon above the navigation menu. But it is now coming always menu stuck with the top of the page. How to provide space above the topnav so that I can put my code for social icon on the top of the page. All the time menu comes above the page and social bars or any text is now showing above the top of menu. I want to show some icon and text on the top of menu.

```js
 function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
 body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
   padding-left: 50px;

}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;

}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a class="active" href="../index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  <a  title="Pregnancy" href="../c-pregnancy">Pregnancy</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the following what you mean? If not you need to clarify your question by providing an example (image) of what you want.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.social {
  background: red;
  padding: 5px 50px;
}



.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
   padding-left: 50px;

}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;

}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="social">
  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">android</i></a>
</div>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a class="active" href="../index.php">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
  <a  title="Pregnancy" href="../c-pregnancy">Pregnancy</a>

  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
```